# asp.net check Context.User confirmed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, iprincipal

The project is C# asp.net 4.5 (not MVC).

When in my master page, or an aspx/ascx page, you can tell if a user is in a role:

```
<% if(Context.User.IsInRole("the role to check")) { blaw blaw } %>
```

Is there a similar way to check if a user has 'confirmed' their account?
Something like

```
<% if(Context.User.IsConfirmed()) { blaw blaw } %>
```

Do I just need to derive my own IPrincipal based class?

Comment: Define "confirmed".  You could make a role.

Comment: Yes that is possible. You will need to [create a custom principal identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-principal-identity) and then add `IsConfirmed` method/property to it and provide the implementation for it. Then you can use it wherever you need to.